# Users able to edit records not owned by them inspite of OWD Setting Public Read Only

Tags: user-record, owd, userrecordaccess

- The OWD setting on Opportunity is Public Read Only
- Permission on
  Opportunity  for User Profile is:  Create, Edit, Delete, Read, View
  All.
- No permission to Modify All
- Sharing Rules are not defined for this object.

I though the above settings only allow the record owner and any one above in hierarchy to record owner the ability to edit records. However, all users can edit Opportunity records not owned by them.

What am i missing to allow only the Owners and the managers of the record owners to edit the record. ?

Comment: How are users editing records? Through visualforce/LWC, API calls, or something else? Are the edits being made by code executed from a trigger, or through a workflow field update?

Comment: Manually , by clicking on the record, and changing field values. eg open any opportunity (not owned by the user),  change a field value.

Comment: Do you use account teams or opportunity teams?

Comment: yes we use Opportunity teams.

Comment: Is there a permission set that grants Modify All on opportunity?

Comment: No there is no permission set. However with the same settings as mentioned in my original question I am able to only allow only owners and anyone above in role hierarchy to owner to edit records.  I changed and re-changed  the 'Public Read Only' flag on sharing settings, and that seemed to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the card. I am able to only allow only owners and anyone above in role hierarchy to owner to edit records. Not sure why my test failed,  but I changed and re-changed the 'Public Read Only' flag on sharing settings, and that seemed to have worked for me.